# 1 pixel distortion with 3 columns of the same height in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

can you guys help me figure out why, when I am applying the display:table to make columns of the same height, my row is shrinking in 1px (compared to my other containers) as shown on the attached pic? It seems my main content gets resized when my @media instruction fires out.

[image]

I am using Bootstrap 3.6 and standard html/css and testing on Google Chrome. Here's the code:

**CSS**

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

header, footer {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  color: #222;
  padding: 20px;
}

aside {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

article {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 40px;
}

.menu {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.menu h4 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: darkorange;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bannerside {
  background-color: #333;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.bannerside a {
  color:#FFF;
}

.bannerside-top div {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.bannerside-top a {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-cst {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn-rect-30-wide {
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.btn-rect-60 {
  width: 90px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.btn-sqr-60 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.photo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #7A9;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 8px #777;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.navy {
  background: navy;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .menu h4 {
    display: inline;
  }
  .menu a {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu .btn-cst {
    width: 33%;
    height: 33%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

  }

}

/* 3 col same height fix */
@media (min-width:768px) {
  .container-sm-height {
    display: table;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
  .row-sm-height {
    display: table-row;
  }
  .col-sm-height {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
  }
}


**HTML**
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='app.css' rel='stylesheet'>
   </head>
   <body>
  <header class="container-fluid ">HEADER</header>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="bannerside bannerside-top visible-md ">
        <div>
           <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 pink" value="AD1">
              <h6>
                 Advertisment Link 1
              </h6>
           </a>
           <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 red" value="AD2">
              <h6>
                 Advertisment Link 2
              </h6>
           </a>
           <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 navy" value="AD3">
              <h6>
                 Advertisment Link 3
              </h6>
           </a>
           <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 green" value="AD4">
              <h6>
                 Advertisment Link 4
              </h6>
           </a>
           <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 orange" value="AD5">
              <h6>
                 Advertisment Link 5
              </h6>
           </a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid container-sm-height">
     <div class="row row-sm-height">
        <section class="col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3 col-lg-8 col-lg-push-2 col-sm-height">
           <article>
              <h2>
                 Title 1
              </h2>
              <div class="photo">
                 <br /><br />
                 GFX 1<br />
                 <br /><br />
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                 <p class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
                 </p>
                 <p class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                    <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-30-wide red" value="more..." />
                 </p>
              </div>
           </article>
           <article>
              <h2>
                 Title 2
              </h2>
              <div class="photo">
                 <br /><br />
                 GFX 1<br />
                 <br /><br />
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                 <p class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
                 </p>
                 <p class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                    <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-30-wide red" value="more..." />
                 </p>
              </div>
           </article>
           <article>
              <h2>
                 Really big and annoying title 123456789
              </h2>
              <div class="photo">
                 <br /><br />
                 GFX 1<br />
                 <br /><br />
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                 <p class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
                 </p>
                 <p class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                    <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-30-wide red" value="more..." />
                 </p>
              </div>
           </article>
        </section>
        <aside class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9 col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-8 col-sm-height">
           <h4>
              MENU ITEMS
           </h4>
           <div class="menu">
              <a href="">
                 <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-60 pink" value="LM1">
                 <h4>
                    Link Menu 1
                 </h4>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                 <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-60 orange" value="LM2">
                 <h4>
                    Link Menu 2
                 </h4>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                 <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-60 navy" value="LM3">
                 <h4>
                    Link Menu 3
                 </h4>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                 <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-60 green" value="LM4">
                 <h4>
                    Link Menu 4
                 </h4>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                 <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-60 blue" value="LM5">
                 <h4>
                    Link Menu 5
                 </h4>
              </a>
           </div>
        </aside>
        <aside class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 bannerside hidden-md col-sm-height">
           <div class="menu">
              <a href="">
                 <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 pink" value="AD1">
                 <h6>
                    Advertisment Link 1
                 </h6>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                 <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 red" value="AD2">
                 <h6>
                    Advertisment Link 2
                 </h6>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                 <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 navy" value="AD3">
                 <h6>
                    Advertisment Link 3
                 </h6>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                 <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 green" value="AD4">
                 <h6>
                    Advertisment Link 4
                 </h6>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                 <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 orange" value="AD5">
                 <h6>
                    Advertisment Link 5
                 </h6>
              </a>
           </div>
        </aside>
     </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="container-fluid">FOOTER</footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a lot going on that's outside the scope of Bootstrap. Can you minimize your code to clarify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change the style class `.row-sm-height { display: table-row;}` to `.row-sm-height { display: table-cell;}` . Here are the [demo](http://www.bootply.com/XeV3CNph8I#)

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

header, footer {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  color: #222;
  padding: 20px;
}

aside {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

article {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 40px;
}

.menu {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.menu h4 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: darkorange;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bannerside {
  background-color: #333;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.bannerside a {
  color:#FFF;
}

.bannerside-top div {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.bannerside-top a {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-cst {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
}

.btn-rect-30-wide {
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.btn-rect-60 {
  width: 90px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.btn-sqr-60 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.photo {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #7A9;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 8px #777;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.navy {
  background: navy;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .menu h4 {
    display: inline;
  }
  .menu a {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu .btn-cst {
    width: 33%;
    height: 33%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

  }

}

/* 3 col same height fix */
@media (min-width:768px) {
  .container-sm-height {
    display: table;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
  .row-sm-height {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  .col-sm-height {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='app.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  </head>

  <body>

    <header class="container-fluid ">HEADER</header>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="bannerside bannerside-top visible-md ">
          <div>
             <a href="">
                <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 pink" value="AD1">
                <h6>
                  Advertisment Link 1
                </h6>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 red" value="AD2">
                <h6>
                  Advertisment Link 2
                </h6>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 navy" value="AD3">
                <h6>
                  Advertisment Link 3
                </h6>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 green" value="AD4">
                <h6>
                  Advertisment Link 4
                </h6>
              </a>
              <a href="">
                <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 orange" value="AD5">
                <h6>
                  Advertisment Link 5
                </h6>
              </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    <div class="container-fluid container-sm-height">

      <div class="row row-sm-height">


        <section class="col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3 col-lg-8 col-lg-push-2 col-sm-height">
          <article>
            <h2>
              Title 1
            </h2>
            <div class="photo">
              <br /><br />
              GFX 1<br />
              <br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <p class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
              </p>
              <p class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-30-wide red" value="more..." />
              </p>
            </div>
          </article>

          <article>
            <h2>
              Title 2
            </h2>
            <div class="photo">
              <br /><br />
              GFX 1<br />
              <br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <p class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
              </p>
              <p class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-30-wide red" value="more..." />
              </p>
            </div>
          </article>

          <article>
            <h2>
              Really big and annoying title 123456789
            </h2>
            <div class="photo">
              <br /><br />
              GFX 1<br />
              <br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <p class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
              </p>
              <p class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-30-wide red" value="more..." />
              </p>
            </div>
          </article>

        </section>



        <aside class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9 col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-8 col-sm-height">
          <h4>
            MENU ITEMS
          </h4>
          <div class="menu">
            <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-60 pink" value="LM1">
              <h4>
                Link Menu 1
              </h4>
            </a>
            <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-60 orange" value="LM2">
              <h4>
              Link Menu 2
              </h4>
            </a>
            <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-60 navy" value="LM3">
              <h4>
                Link Menu 3
              </h4>
            </a>
            <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-60 green" value="LM4">
              <h4>
                Link Menu 4
              </h4>
            </a>
            <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-rect-60 blue" value="LM5">
              <h4>
                Link Menu 5
              </h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </aside>



        <aside class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 bannerside hidden-md col-sm-height">
          <div class="menu">
            <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 pink" value="AD1">
              <h6>
                Advertisment Link 1
              </h6>
            </a>
            <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 red" value="AD2">
              <h6>
                Advertisment Link 2
              </h6>
            </a>
            <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 navy" value="AD3">
              <h6>
                Advertisment Link 3
              </h6>
            </a>
            <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 green" value="AD4">
              <h6>
                Advertisment Link 4
              </h6>
            </a>
            <a href="">
              <input type="button" class="btn-cst btn-sqr-60 orange" value="AD5">
              <h6>
                Advertisment Link 5
              </h6>
            </a>
          </div>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="container-fluid">FOOTER</footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Fazil, it worked, I just did not understand the reason why, since now I am inserting a 3 'cells' inside of a 'cell' and not a 'row".